# Functional equation $(x-y)(f(x)+f(y))=(x+y)f(x-y)$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

I have proved that the functional equation, $(x-y)(f(x)+f(y))=(x+y)f(x-y)$, has the following results:

- $f(0)=0$,
- $f$ is an odd function.

It is clear that $f(x)=cx$ for $c \in \mathbb R$ is a solution. But I could not conclude my solution.

Comment: what is the domain and the image of $f$? $f$ is continuous or differentiable or sth?

Comment: If you plug in $y=x/2$ then you get a relation between $f(x)$ and $f(x/2)$ (which can be iterated). This together with an assumption of differentiability at $x=0$ would give $f(x)=cx$.

Comment: yes by using differentiability i also found that solution but $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is only given condition

Comment: Kindly place additional insights (differentiability conclusions etc.) into the question box, this improves the context of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Let $y = x - 1$. This gives us that
$$
  f(x) + f(x - 1) = (2x - 1) f(1). \quad (\star)
$$

This implies
$$
  f(x + 1) + f(x) = (2x + 1) f(1)
$$
and adding this to Equation $(\star)$ gives us
$$
  2f(x) + f(x + 1) + f(x - 1) = 4x f(1). \quad (\star \star)
$$

Letting $x = x + 1$ and $y = x - 1$ in the functional equation gives us that
$$
  2(f(x + 1) + f(x - 1)) = 2x f(2) \implies f(x + 1) + f(x - 1) = xf(2).
$$

Substituting this into Equation $(\star \star)$ gives us
$$
  f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x \left(4f(1) - f(2) \right)
$$
for all $x$.